# apply aggregate function in orderby clause in dql

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

- i have a select dql query like this-

  ```
  $i=0;
  $max_result=50;
  $qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
  $from='Entities\EventVisitor evtvstr';
  $qb->select('evtvstr.user, evtvstr.metadata, u.id')
  ->add('from', $from)
  ->groupBy('evtvstr.user')
  ->orderBy('?')
  ->setFirstResult($i)
  ->setMaxResults($max_result)
  ->distinct();
  $query = $qb->getQuery();
  $query->getSQl();
  $results = $query->getResult();
  print_r($results);
  ```
- now i want to apply max(created) (at ? in my query) in order by clause.
  how can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `->addSelect('max(created) AS HIDDEN max_created')` and then order by `max_created`

```
$qb=$this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$from='Entities\EventVisitor evtvstr';
$qb->select('evtvstr.user, evtvstr.metadata, u.id')
->addSelect('max(created) AS HIDDEN max_created')
->add('from', $from)
->groupBy('evtvstr.user')
->orderBy('max_created')
->setFirstResult($i)
->setMaxResults($max_result)
->distinct();
```